# How to handle asynchronous requests to rest apis in an ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, rest, nsurlconnection

Let's say I want to use the rest api of some service, Twitbookr, to get a user's profile information. So I get the user to log in via my app and I get the credentials needed to make the call.

After this I load a new ViewController. I want to populate the fields in this view with the user's profile information. So I make my first call to the api:

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req 
                     queue:NSOperation.mainQueue 
                     completionHandler:
    ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        // successfully fetch data using credentials
        // assume complete code here including dispatch_async etc
        self.data = data;
    })];
```

Then I want to use the data:

```
    self.nameLabel.text = [self.data objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.userid = [self.data objectForKey:@"userid"];
```

But the request hasn't finished yet, so the program throws an error.

And I want to make more calls to get different types of data, for example, the pictures from the frontpage album, which rely on the userid which I can only get from the request above. So how do I make my next subsequent call making sure I already have the userid from the first call?

What's the correct way to handle this situation?

Should I be using synchronous requests instead? 
Should I put up a loading symbol until all of my requests are done? If so, how do I test that the requests have actually finished? And what's the point of them being asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req 
                 queue:NSOperation.mainQueue 
                 completionHandler:
^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    // successfully fetch data using credentials
    self.data = data;

    //Use data here
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update UI here
        });
})];
```

When you use AsynchronousRequest,use data in completion block. I think your code

```
        self.nameLabel.text = self.data.name;
```

is wrong,because self.data looks like NSData,and it not has a property of name
Update:As Mike said,only update UI on main thread.

Comment: He cannot use the data in the completion block to update the UI, unless it is wrapped in a dispatch_async to the main thread, otherwise it will crash.